# KKGridView vs AQGridView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Anyone have a good comparison between [KKGridView](https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/KKGridView) and [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView)?

Is there a reason to use one over the other?

Comment: AQGridView is full of crazy bugs when trying to do horizontal grid views. You can get around it, but it's lots of work.

Comment: Take a look at GMGridView. I like it more than KKGridView

Comment: Update: as mentioned in its [read me on Github](https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/KKGridView), KKGridView has recently been deprecated, due to some new features coming in iOS 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AQGridView looks really unstable (there are lots of issues opened on GitHub). Even its demo project works with bugs. I think it's a good reason to don't use AQGridView